# Linear gradient brush with c# on windows phone 8.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am creating a linear gradient on left mouse button up. This is the code which 
which I am trying to implement the above linear gradient brush

```
 private void r10_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            r10.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Purple, Colors.Gray, 90);
        }
```

If you have got any idea please help

Comment: This is a terrible way to ask a question. You didn't give the slightest hint what the problem is. w.b. i probably right.

Comment: whaat?? sir really??

Comment: Yes, really. You still have not asked a question! - Do you get an error? Do you expect any screen action from creating a brush ? Have you read even the most introductory pages to this site (or about LinearGradientBrush)?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you're using doesn't exist in Silverlight. You can rewrite your code this way:

```
var gradients = new GradientStopCollection
{
    new GradientStop {Color = Colors.Purple, Offset = 0},
    new GradientStop {Color = Colors.Gray, Offset = 1}
};

r10.Background.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(gradients, 90);
```